# How to get array values from attribute?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, attributes

I am making application in angular 6 and As i am sending and receiving data in dynamic mode, i am in the need to pass and retrieve the array values through attribute for which i have used the following,

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" id="list" [attr.parent_id]="123">
    <li #li class="media p-2 column" *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index;" [attr.items]="item"> {{item.name}} </li>
</ul>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChildren("li") listElements: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLLIElement>>;
  name = 'Angular';
  items = [
    { "id": 123, "name": "hello" },
    { "id": 234, "name": "world" }
  ]
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.printElements();
    this.listElements.changes.subscribe(_ => this.printElements());
  }

  private printElements() {
    const elements = this.listElements.toArray();
    elements.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element.nativeElement.getAttribute('items'));
    })
  }
}
```

**Working Stackblitz:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jndtv1

Here instead of

```
console.log(element.nativeElement.getAttribute('items'));
```

(which gives [object object])

If i include JSON.stringify,

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(element.nativeElement.getAttribute('items')));
```

(gives "[object object]")

Kindly help me to get the array values through the attribute using only **Pure javascript/typescript** without jquery.

Comment: `console.log(element.nativeElement.innerText);`

Comment: @ritaj, I need to get the value only through attribute and i should not use innerText.. That too i need the entire array from that attribute.. ```element.nativeElement.innerText``` gives only the name value..

Comment: can you check this?

Comment: @Asanka, Which?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-guqyan?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Asanka, Thats what i have mentioned in the above comment, i need to get whole array from attribute without using ```innerHTML``` or ```innerText```

Comment: but why? you have the itemArray already

Comment: @ManiRaj I am getting "Hello" and "world" printed in the console in your stackblitz project. Where are you getting object object?

Comment: @Debojyoti, Check now, it was changed for checking with innerText, KIndly check with the code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this, not the good way but it works:

in your html:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" id="list" [attr.parent_id]="123">
    <li #li class="media p-2 column" *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index;" 
  [attr.items]="item | json"> {{item.name}} </li>
</ul>
```

in your ts:

```
private printElements() {
    const elements = this.listElements.toArray();
    elements.forEach(element => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(element.nativeElement.getAttribute('items')).id);
       console.log(JSON.parse(element.nativeElement.getAttribute('items')).name);
    })
  }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrehs1)